# Why does OpenSSL 0.9.7h version is faster than OpenSSL 1.0.1c Version?

Tags: performance, openssl

Can someone tell me why openssl 0.9.7h work faster than openssl 1.0.1c?
Both with default configuration on same computer and in ubuntu 12.04
aes speed test in openssl 0.9.7h 50% work faster than openssl 1.0.1c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dip in performance could be due to the following reasons:

1. Version of OpenSSL being Negotiation (In 0.9.7h it may be SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0, but in OpenSSL 1.0.1c, it may be TLS 1.2)
2. It may be due to the Cipher List being negotiation. If you are using the default cipher list, it might have been changed by OpenSSL. (TLS 1.2 Ciphers are more secure and hence consume more CPU)